# how to get image from directory to slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get every image from the folder and show it in a jQuery slider. I got some scratch code from other sites but I didn't get my output. Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- directorySlider Javascript file -->
    <script src="js/directorySlider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directorySlider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#slider-main').directorySlider({
            animation: 'fade',
            filebase: 'img_',
            directory: 'images/',
            extension: 'jpg',
            numslides: 2,
            height: 200, 
            width:  483,
            timeout: 100
        })
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="directorySlider" id="slider-main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

My project directory:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: FYI You're including jQuery and the directorySlider twice. Remove one of each of them.

Comment: You do have an `images/` folder with `jpg` images with file names like `img_1.jpg`, correct?

Comment: which one i need to remove

Comment: yes i have images/ folder

Comment: someone please help to solve my prob

Comment: you need a server side script to get the directory contents. Client side javascript can't do that

Comment: can u give me sample code please....

Comment: that depends on server languages available. It's not hard to find out how to glob a directory in any language

Comment: Take a look at the GitHub repo for the JS you are using I'm sure you'll find more direction there. https://github.com/justinwhall/directorySlider

Comment: if the name and number of your images are fix, then you can simple create a javascript array and store their name in that array and use that array in your slide show. otherwise as @charlietfl has mentioned, you have to have a server-side script to create the list of images in the directory on the server.